# Android WebView: How do I horizontally scroll between different pages?

Tags: android, webview, horizontal-scrolling

I have several HTML pages that I'd like to be able to scroll horizontally, kind of like how you would read a book or a magazine. But instead of a totally smooth scrolling horizontally, I would like each page to kind of click into place as I scroll.

What is the best way I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use a `ViewFlipper` with multipe `WebViews` and add animations when you flipp through your views.

Also you would have to add a `GestureDetector` and implement the `onFling()` method.

Depending on how many webpages you have you might want to limit the amount of `WebView` instances and resuse them and just load another page when they are shown.